# In Pygame for loops collision-detection isn't working

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop, pygame, collision-detection

I'm sorry if this isn't a super general question, but it's such a specific thing that I just know should work, and it just doesn't.

Why doesn't the collision detection from the green player hitting the yellow box work?

I'm sorry for all of the other clutter, but I couldn't find anything to delete to make the code smaller whilst still remaining the core game. Right now it's mostly barebones.
'    import pygame, sys, time

```
pygame.init()

isRunning = True

windowWidth = 1280
windowHeight = 720

playerHeight = 64
playerWidth = 64
playerX = (windowWidth / 2) - (playerWidth / 2) + 100
playerY = (windowHeight / 2) - (playerHeight / 2)
playerXLate = playerX
playerYLate = playerY
playerSpeed = 4

blockHeight = 64
blockWidth = 64
blockX = 0
blockY = 0

number = 3

playerMovingForewards = False
playerMovingLeft = False
playerMovingBackwards = False
playerMovingRight = False

playerColor = (0, 255, 0)
blockColor = (255, 255, 0)
backgroundColor = (0, 0, 255)

window = pygame.display.set_mode((windowWidth, windowHeight))

while isRunning == True:

    Map = open('Map', 'r')
    mapY = Map.readlines()
    mapX = mapY[0].split()

    for y in range(len(mapY)):
            mapX = mapY[y]
            for x in range(len(mapX)):
                    if mapX[x] == "1":
                            if playerX + playerWidth >= (x * 64) and playerX <= (x * 64) + blockWidth and playerY + playerHeight >= (y * 64) and playerY <= (y * 64) + blockHeight:
                                    playerX = playerXLate
                                    playerY = playerYLate
                            pygame.draw.rect (window, (blockColor), ((x / 2) * 64, y * 64, blockWidth, blockHeight))

    Map.close()

    playerXLate = playerX
    playerYLate = playerY

    for event in pygame.event.get():

            if (event.type == pygame.QUIT):
                    isRunning = False
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()

            if(event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN):
                    if (event.key == pygame.K_w):
                            playerMovingForewards = True
                    if (event.key == pygame.K_a):
                            playerMovingLeft = True
                    if (event.key == pygame.K_s):
                            playerMovingBackwards = True
                    if (event.key == pygame.K_d):
                            playerMovingRight = True

            if(event.type == pygame.KEYUP):
                    if (event.key == pygame.K_w):
                            playerMovingForewards = False
                    if (event.key == pygame.K_a):
                            playerMovingLeft = False
                    if (event.key == pygame.K_s):
                            playerMovingBackwards = False
                    if (event.key == pygame.K_d):
                            playerMovingRight = False

    if playerMovingForewards == True:
            playerY = playerY + -playerSpeed
    if playerMovingLeft == True:
            playerX = playerX + -playerSpeed
    if playerMovingBackwards == True:
            playerY = playerY + playerSpeed
    if playerMovingRight == True:
            playerX = playerX + playerSpeed

    #Graphics (Start)

    pygame.draw.rect (window, (playerColor), (playerX, playerY, playerWidth, playerHeight))

    pygame.display.update()

    pygame.draw.rect (window, (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, windowWidth, windowHeight))

    pygame.draw.rect (window, (backgroundColor), (windowWidth - windowWidth, windowHeight - windowHeight, windowWidth, windowHeight))

    #Graphics (End)

    time.sleep(0.01)

pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

and the "Map" file is:

```
1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
1 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I was playing around with the detection and I figured out that I had to divide the x variable by 2. I still don't know how to but for some reason it does. I think it shouldn't work like this but it does for some reason.